# Which socket.io version do I have to install to make works the method "of" from Server class with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, socket.io, dependencies, nestjs, backend

I'm setting up my sockets handlers for my web server in nestJS.
All my npm modules are at the latest version with 0 vulnerability.

In all my gateways, I have this following problem :

For each line `"io.of("/random namespace")"`, my nest logger gives me this error :

```
nest_container   | TypeError: io.of is not a function
```

3 days ago I didn't have this error.

```
my socket.io version :  "version": "4.5.3"
my typescript version :  "version": "4.9.4"
```

Here is my code :

```
import { MessageBody, SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer, ConnectedSocket, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect, OnGatewayInit } from "@nestjs/websockets";
import { Server as SocketIOServer, Socket, Namespace } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io/node_modules/socket.io';
import { Logger, UseGuards } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { MessageService } from "./message/message.service";
import { MessageEntity } from "./message/message.entity";
import * as jsrsasign from 'jsrsasign';

interface MessageChat {
    room: string;
    isChannel: boolean;
    content?: string;
}

interface MessageToSend {
    sender?: string;
    room: string;
    content: string;
}

@WebSocketGateway({transports: ['websocket'], namespace: '/chat'})
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    private server: SocketIOServer;
    private logger: Logger = new Logger('ChatGateway');
    private chatNamespace: Namespace;

    constructor(
        private messageService: MessageService,
    ) 
    {}

    private socketMap: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>;

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('websocket'))
    handleConnection(client: Socket) {
        if (client.handshake.auth['token'] != null) {
            let pseudo = jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.parse(client.handshake.auth['token']).payloadObj!.login;
            this.socketMap.set(pseudo, client.id);
            this.logger.log(`${pseudo} is connected`);
            console.log(this.socketMap);
        }
    }

    afterInit(server: SocketIOServer) {
        this.server = new SocketIOServer();
        this.chatNamespace = server.of('chat');
        this.logger.log('Init');
    }

    handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
        if (client.handshake.auth['token'] != null) {
            let pseudo = jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.parse(client.handshake.auth['token']).payloadObj!.login;
            this.socketMap.delete(pseudo);
            this.logger.log(`${pseudo} is disconnected`);
        }
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('addMessage')
    handleNewMessage(@MessageBody() blop: MessageChat, @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
        let pseudo = "unknow";
        let token = client.handshake.query.token;
        if (client.handshake.auth['token'] != null) {
            pseudo = jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.parse(client.handshake.auth['token']).payloadObj!.login;
        }
        let sender: string = client.id;
        this.socketMap.set(pseudo, sender);
        console.log('ChatGateway::handleNewMessage : ', blop, pseudo);
        let data: MessageEntity = {
            id: undefined,
            room: blop.room,
            isChannel: blop.isChannel,
            sender: pseudo,
            content: blop.content,
            date: undefined
        }
        this.messageService.create(data);
        let toSend : MessageToSend = {sender: pseudo, room: blop.room, content: blop.content};
        if (!blop.isChannel)
        {
            client.emit('selfMessage', toSend);
            let socketDest = this.socketMap.get(blop.room);
            if (socketDest != undefined)
            {
                console.log("message", blop.room, pseudo, blop.content);
                this.logger.log(socketDest);
                console.log(toSend);
                console.log(this.chatNamespace.sockets);
                //this.chatNamespace = this.server.of('/chat');
                this.chatNamespace.sockets.get(socketDest).emit('messagePrivate', toSend);
                //this.server.sockets.sockets.get(socketDest).emit("messagePrivate", toSend);
                this.logger.log("msg send");
            }
            //this.messageService.findByPrivate(blop.room, pseudo).then((data) => console.log(data));
        }
        else
        {
            
            this.messageService.findByChannel(blop.room).then((data) => console.log(data));
        }
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('history')
    handleHistory(@MessageBody() data: MessageChat, @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
        if (data.isChannel)
        {
            this.messageService.findByChannel(data.room).then((data) => client.emit("history", data));
        }
        else
        {
            let pseudo = jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.parse(client.handshake.auth['token']).payloadObj!.login;
            this.messageService.findByPrivate(data.room, pseudo).then((data) => client.emit("history", data));
        }
    }
    // // @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
    // @SubscribeMessage('privateMessage')
    // async handlePrivateEvent(@MessageBody() data: MessageChat, @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket): Promise<void> {
    //     let pseudo = jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.parse(client.handshake.auth['token']).payloadObj;
    //     console.log(pseudo, client.id, data.room, data.content);
    //     client.emit('message', { sender: client.id, room: data.room, content: data.content });          
    // }
}
```

This is my log from nest :

```
nest_container   | /usr/src/app/nest_project/src/chat/chat.gateway.ts:46
nest_container   |         this.chatNamespace = server.of('chat');
nest_container   |                                     ^
nest_container   | TypeError: server.of is not a function
nest_container   |     at ChatGateway.afterInit (/usr/src/app/nest_project/src/chat/chat.gateway.ts:46:37)
nest_container   |     at ConsumerObserver.next (/usr/src/app/nest_project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:161:25)
nest_container   |     at SafeSubscriber.Subscriber._next (/usr/src/app/nest_project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:119:22)
nest_container   |     at SafeSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/usr/src/app/nest_project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:75:12)
nest_container   |     at ReplaySubject._subscribe (/usr/src/app/nest_project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts:80:18)
nest_container   |     at ReplaySubject.Observable._trySubscribe (/usr/src/app/nest_project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:244:19)
nest_container   |     at ReplaySubject.Subject._trySubscribe (/usr/src/app/nest_project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subject.ts:113:31)
```

I maybe found the problem,
when i call the "of" method of my Server class, somehow the compiler is getting confused and is trying to call the "of" function of the rxjs module...

Is it possible, and how can i avoid that ?

Comment: I have exactly the same error if I import :  
"import { Server, Socket, Namespace } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io/node_modules/socket.io';"
or if I import :  
"import { Server, Socket, Namespace } from 'socket.io';

Answer (score 2):

I finally decided to stop using the namespace feature of socket.io, the associate functions are just not working.

Stocking all the entire sockets in a map container is easier and it just works.

```
@WebSocketGateway({transports: ['websocket'], namespace: '/chat'})
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    @WebSocketServer() server: SocketIOServer;
    private logger: Logger = new Logger('ChatGateway');

    constructor(
        private messageService: MessageService,
    ) 
    {}

 private socketMap: Map<string, Socket> = new Map<string, Socket>;

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('websocket'))
    handleConnection(client: Socket) {
        if (client.handshake.auth['token'] != null) {
            let pseudo = jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.parse(client.handshake.auth['token']).payloadObj!.login;
            this.socketMap.set(pseudo, client);
            this.logger.log(`${pseudo} is connected`);
        }
    }

    handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
        if (client.handshake.auth['token'] != null) {
            let pseudo = jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.parse(client.handshake.auth['token']).payloadObj!.login;
            this.socketMap.delete(pseudo);
            this.logger.log(`${pseudo} is disconnected`);
        }
    }

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('websocket'))
    @SubscribeMessage('addMessage')
    handleNewMessage(@MessageBody() blop: MessageChat, @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
        let pseudo = "unknow";
        if (client.handshake.auth['token'] != null) {
            pseudo = jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.parse(client.handshake.auth['token']).payloadObj!.login;
        }
        this.socketMap.set(pseudo, client);
        console.log('ChatGateway::handleNewMessage : ', blop, pseudo);
        let data: MessageEntity = {
            id: undefined,
            room: blop.room,
            isChannel: blop.isChannel,
            sender: pseudo,
            content: blop.content,
            date: undefined
        }
        this.messageService.create(data);
        let toSend : MessageToSend = {sender: pseudo, room: blop.room, content: blop.content};
        if (!blop.isChannel)
        {
            client.emit('selfMessage', toSend);
            let socketDest = this.socketMap.get(blop.room);
            if (socketDest != undefined)
            {
                console.log("message", blop.room, pseudo, blop.content);
                socketDest.emit("messagePrivate", toSend);
                this.logger.log("msg send");
            }
        }
        else (...)
```